# XML Namespace in field line java

Tags: java, xml, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I want to my response SOAP be like:

```
<code>
<NS2:code1 xmlns:NS2="namespace">0000</NS2:code1>
<NS3:code2 xmlns:NS3="namespace">0001</NS3:code2>
</code>
```

How can I manipulate this in java/camel cxf?
I've tried to add

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
```

but the body stayed like this

```
<ns2:response xmlns:ns2="responseNamespace" xmlns:ns5="namespace" >
<code>
<ns5:code>0000</ns5:code>
<ns5:code1>0001</ns5:code1>
</code>
```

How can I declare namespace in the same line like the first example?

My java data class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @XmlType(name = "code", propOrder = { "code1", "code2" })
public class Code {
    @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
    protected String code1;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
    protected String code2;
}
```

Comment: How are these `xmlns:ns2="responseNamespace" xmlns:ns5="namespace"` defined and resolved?

Comment: What I mean is if you are converting Java classes to XML, are you using an annotation to define the namespace and if so, what is the value?

Comment: @hfontanez My java data class:
`
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "code", propOrder = {
    "code1",
    "code2"
})
public class Code {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
    protected String code1;
 
 @XmlElement(namespace = "namespace")
    protected String code2;
 
}`

Comment: Can I manipulate to declaration of namespace be in the same line? like the first example

Comment: You should've edited your question and post that last comment in there. I just did that for you.

Comment: it doesn't look like you're defining the namespace anywhere in there.